# Can I get GADTs with missing constructors to fail at compile time?

Tags: haskell, gadt

I'm just starting to learn GADTs and it's a little disappointing that if I fail to include a key constructor it still compiles. Is there something I can do to catch this at compile time?

This compiles:

```
data Expr t where
    NumVal     :: Num a => a -> Expr a
    -- StrVal     :: String -> Expr String
    Add        :: Num a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
    Multiply   :: Num a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
    HelloWorld :: Expr String -> Expr String

eval :: Expr t -> t
eval (NumVal n)       = n
-- eval (StrVal s)       = s
eval (Add e1 e2)      = eval e1 + eval e2
eval (Multiply e1 e2) = eval e1 * eval e2
eval (HelloWorld e1)  = "Hello " <> eval e1
```

ghci:

```
Haskell> eval . HelloWorld . StrVal $ "Nate"

<interactive>:38:21: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: StrVal :: [Char] -> Expr String
```

To be fair, calling `StrVal` here is the clue that it doesn't exist, so as long as my code uses the evaluator for the GADT I'm exporting I should be able to catch this. But if my code doesn't need to use all aspects of the evaluator it looks like the completeness of my test coverage is the only thing preventing this from shipping.

My intuition suggests that there should be a way for the compiler to see that I'm using the type `Expr String` and that there is no way to construct it.

```
data Expr t where
    ...
    HelloWorld :: Expr String -> Expr String
```

--
EDIT:
The point was made in the comments that I could always provide an instance of `Num` for `String`. And indeed if I do that, this runs just fine:

```
Haskell> eval . HelloWorld . NumVal $ "Nate"
"Hello Nate"
```

However, simplifying the original example to just `Int`s still type checks without a way to construct an `Expr String`.

```
data Expr t where
    IntVal     :: Int -> Expr Int
    --StrVal     :: String -> Expr String
    Add        :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
    Multiply   :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
    HelloWorld :: Expr String -> Expr String

eval :: Expr t -> t
eval (IntVal n)       = n
--eval (StrVal s)       = s
eval (Add e1 e2)      = eval e1 + eval e2
eval (Multiply e1 e2) = eval e1 * eval e2
eval (HelloWorld e1)  = "Hello " <> eval e1
```

Comment: But there is a way to construct it: given you make an `instance Num String`, there is no problem.

Comment: Why should the compiler know something that isn't true? There's nothing preventing `[Char]` from being an instance of `Num`.

Comment: HA! Good point. But even if I change out the `Num` bits for just plain `Int`s I still have the same problem.

Comment: In general, detecting whether a GADT type like `Expr String` is inhabited of not is undecidable. Therefore, the compiler can not detect that. The compiler could, in principle, use static analysis and approximate the problem ("warning some but not all times"). That feature is non trivial to implement, and probably not too much requested, so it was not implemented.

Comment: "My intuition suggests that there should be a way for the compiler to see that I'm using the type `Expr String` and that there is no way to construct it." Note that [the `absurd` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Void.html#v:absurd) relies on being able to use uninhabited types.

Comment: "it looks like the completeness of my test coverage is the only thing preventing this from shipping" Is that not a perfectly valid solution?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, that's a great example. I was thinking about whether or not a function that relies on uninhabitable types could be useful. But it sounds like GHC can at least tell it's uninhabitable because `Void` is defined as a data type with no constructor.

Comment: @chi huh. I guess if it's undecidable that would be why it doesn't reject it! I can't easily see why it's undecidable but that certainly answers the question.

Comment: You can write e.g. `data T (n :: Nat)` where `T n` is inhabited iff `n` is even. With more effort, ... iff `n` is prime. With huge effort, ... iff `n` encodes a halting program. This is commonly done in languages like Coq or Agda with full dependent types, but one can adapt the same definitions to GADTs. GADTs are very powerful.